# how to get HTML element and bypass *ngIf in angular testing

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular-unit-test

I'm trying to get the the div element, but it's always null in [element variable in spec], I tried detect changes , autodetect changes,fake async , nothing works ,I know that ngIf is the reason cuz when I use the [hidden] it works, but i need to bypass ngIf, **did I need to add projectServiceMock to the provider ?** Thanks for Help

```
    <div *ngIf="project" class="test1">
       <p>Welcme</p>
    </div>
```

> and spec code is

```
  it('test1',()=>{
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const element: ElementRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.test1'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: Perhaps the value of `project` isn't truthy.

Comment: @R.Richards , the project object is not null , is this what you mean with truthly

Comment: Not null, undefined, empty string, or zero (0).

Comment: @R.Richards no , it has values and not any of this (Not null, undefined, empty string, or zero)

Answer (score 0):

I think `project` is falsy.

Try to see if the following works:

```
 it('test1',()=>{
    component.project = {};
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const element: ElementRef = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.test1'));
    fixture.detectChanges();
    expect(element).toBeTruthy();
  });
```